# xcodebuild failed with return code: 65 - using CLI/Appcenter but no error messages

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcodebuild, fastlane

I've upgraded my React Native app to 0.59 and now when I'm trying to archive my app using AppCenter or the CLI, I have an error code 65 without any messages explaining the problem ...

When I'm building directly from Xcode

Xcode version: 10.2.1
React Native: 0.59

```sh
Strip /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FrenchFounders-gecxqcdasodzgbfdfonlrrdxmrql/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/FrenchFounders/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/FrenchFounders.app/FrenchFounders
    cd /Users/vsts/agent/2.153.2/work/1/s/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode_10.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode_10.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4/bin:/Users/vsts/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/vsts/bin:/Users/vsts/.yarn/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/vsts/.azcopy"
    /Applications/Xcode_10.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FrenchFounders-gecxqcdasodzgbfdfonlrrdxmrql/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/FrenchFounders/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/FrenchFounders.app/FrenchFounders

SetOwnerAndGroup vsts:staff /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FrenchFounders-gecxqcdasodzgbfdfonlrrdxmrql/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/FrenchFounders/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/FrenchFounders.app
    cd /Users/vsts/agent/2.153.2/work/1/s/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode_10.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode_10.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4/bin:/Users/vsts/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/vsts/bin:/Users/vsts/.yarn/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/vsts/.azcopy"
    /usr/sbin/chown -RH vsts:staff /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FrenchFounders-gecxqcdasodzgbfdfonlrrdxmrql/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/FrenchFounders/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/FrenchFounders.app

SetMode u+w,go-w,a+rX /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FrenchFounders-gecxqcdasodzgbfdfonlrrdxmrql/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/FrenchFounders/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/FrenchFounders.app
    cd /Users/vsts/agent/2.153.2/work/1/s/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode_10.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode_10.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4/bin:/Users/vsts/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/vsts/bin:/Users/vsts/.yarn/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/vsts/.azcopy"
    /bin/chmod -RH u+w,go-w,a+rX /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FrenchFounders-gecxqcdasodzgbfdfonlrrdxmrql/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/FrenchFounders/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/FrenchFounders.app

Validate /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FrenchFounders-gecxqcdasodzgbfdfonlrrdxmrql/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/FrenchFounders/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/FrenchFounders.app
    cd /Users/vsts/agent/2.153.2/work/1/s/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode_10.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode_10.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4/bin:/Users/vsts/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/vsts/bin:/Users/vsts/.yarn/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/vsts/.azcopy"
    export PRODUCT_TYPE=com.apple.product-type.application
    builtin-validationUtility /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FrenchFounders-gecxqcdasodzgbfdfonlrrdxmrql/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/FrenchFounders/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/FrenchFounders.app

Touch /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FrenchFounders-gecxqcdasodzgbfdfonlrrdxmrql/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/FrenchFounders/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FrenchFounders.app.dSYM
    cd /Users/vsts/agent/2.153.2/work/1/s/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode_10.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode_10.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4/bin:/Users/vsts/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/vsts/bin:/Users/vsts/.yarn/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/vsts/.azcopy"
    /usr/bin/touch -c /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FrenchFounders-gecxqcdasodzgbfdfonlrrdxmrql/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/FrenchFounders/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FrenchFounders.app.dSYM

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
```

Here is the full log of my AppCenter build: https://gist.github.com/Pandazaur/e61160bda02f0bfe21b85844445db390

How can I get more info about what's wrong in my build process ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution !

1. Start Xcode
2. Run a build/archive
3. Open View > Navigators > Report Navigator
4. Check the log if something is wrong

In my case: I had a script that I ran during the build which exited in error but I didn't handle the error code. So Xcode continued to build and when the build was complete thrown me an error ...

Comment: i got kinda same error in appcenter(app runs fine locally through react-native), and couldnt find the problem till use this solution, Thanks so much.