# Is there a way to see more details in azure pipeline building?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

My company recently upgraded from macOS11 to macOS12 in azure pipeline. But the building project pipeline keeps failing with this error:

*##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65*

But it doesn't show me where the error is in the whole building log...

Does anybody have any idea? Or how can I see more building details?

Comment: Have you checked similar posts like https://stackoverflow.com/a/56704514/18667225 ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the System.debug=true as the environment variable will make the DevOps pipeline show the entire logs.

There are two situations:

***1, YAML pipeline.***

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
- name: system.debug
  value: true #This will help show more log details.

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.
      
      Write-Host "Hello World"
```

***2, Classic pipeline.***

[image]